# Mac Dock For Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is this out there? I tried this a while ago on Linux but it has been a few years, I wonder if there is a better new version of the Mac like dock for Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Cairo Dock](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CairoDock).

[image]

Comment: +1 for this. It also runs fine in minimal systems, with xcompmgr

Answer (score 3):

Gnome-do is nice, but Docky is splitting away from it.  Gnome do is a great replacement for QuickSilver, but you should get Docky separately.  [Instructions to install are available on OMGUbuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/docky-gains-panel-mode-network-docklet.html).  [WebUpd8.org has a nice one-liner command](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/how-to-get-3-dimensional-3d-docky-quick.html) to make Docky go 3D, and look very slick.

In short, run these three commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:docky-core/ppa
sudo apt-get install docky
gconftool-2 -t bool -s /apps/docky-2/Docky/Interface/DockPreferences/Dock1/ThreeDimensional true
```

Another great way to make Ubuntu look really slick is to use [Spatial Desktop](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/spatial-desktop-ubuntu-gorgeous-gnome.html), which is really just a script that modifies your desktop experience through configuration.

Comment: Docky is pure awesomeness!

Answer (score 3):

there's also the option of [Avant Window Navigator](https://launchpad.net/awn) which is quite maclike

Answer (score 2):

Try gnome-do.. Its really nice..

http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/Docky

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.internetling.com/2008/03/24/linux-docks-5-mac-os-x-docks-for-ubuntu-and-other-linux-distros/) post (although a bit dated) does a good job of comparing the major linux docks.